# WordPress WP_Query displays only a part of the total posts

Tags: wordpress

Trying to extract all the postst of a certain type but get only 12 of the total of 25. Here is my code.
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

As can be seen the script only outputs the page 2 from the wp admin panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace

```
'numberposts' => -1,
```

With this

```
'posts_per_page' => -1,
```

Answer (score 0):

You got a 25 posts by this query

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'your-post-type',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 25,
);
```